# Are there ID crosswalks between NPI and OSHPD for California Providers?

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

I am looking for data that contains a list of National Provider Identification Numbers (NPI) that correspond to Medicaid Provider Identification Numbers or OSHPD ID numbers. In particular, does anyone know of a source that contains OSHPD ID and NPI codes for each California Hospital/Clinic?

I am aware that [these NPI files](http://nppes.viva-it.com/NPI_Files.html) contains NPI's linking to providers. But I am curious if there are separate sources that already link California's identifying variables for healthcare providers with the NPI key variable. Otherwise, it would require a significant amount of dirty work to algorithm match them and I may as well see if the work is already done.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, but I've run into the same issue. How did you end up addressing this problem?

Comment: Please do not misuse answers for comments. [It's not that hard to gain some reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll edit my post so it's an answer to the question

Comment: I ended up having to use [fuzzy matching](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/01/27/how-to-perform-a-fuzzy-match-using-sas-functions/) through SAS. Basically, I had to use the complicated art of matching addresses and hospital names between the two datasets to find matches. Even then, I still had to do a lot of manual matches.

Answer (score 2):

I approached this issue by extracting the business address of the OSHPD and matching it to the NPI dataset. I only needed to do it for a handful of Clinics but I imagine the error rate would be relatively low and you would be able to fix/ignore whatever didn't match up, depending on your purpose of course.

The [NPI Core Dataset](http://www.nber.org/data/npi.html) is a little big for excel (2 GB). I attempted to use Tableau, it could manage with a lot of glitching. I would recommend working with these datasets in SQL to make this connection.